# How does eating precede cooking? If influencing the past is useless, then what is the problem?

Tags: free-will

<sub>Source: pp 116-117 , *Think: A Compelling Introduction to Philosophy* (1 ed, 1999) by Simon Blackburn</sub>

> What about the asymmetry between past and future? If they are symmetrical in God's
>   eyes, why is it rational to try to change the future? How can it be any more rational than
>   trying to change the past?
>
> [1.] Well, as I have said, even God does not see us setting about
>   making omelettes, with a slightly previous event of eating one (unless he sees us greedily
>   preparing and devouring second omelettes).
>
> So in fact, it is useless to try to influence the
>   past. That however leaves open a huge and intractable philosophical problem.
>
> [2.] For is it
>   just a matter of fact, a contingency that might have been otherwise, or might be
>   otherwise in different regions of space and time, that we cannot influence the past? If it is
>   only a matter of the patterns seen from the timeless point of view, it seems that it should
>   be. Might the patterns be different elsewhere?

3. 1 confuses me: How does eating omelettes precede making them?
4. What implies the author by 2nd omelettes?
5. I am too confused by 2 even to conjecture its meaning. Please explain and simplify.

Comment: What Blackburn means by  _'timeless point of view'_ is the view as witnessed by an **all-seeing** observer who is outside our realm. Particularly useful in imagining this would be @Regina's parallel of a movie reel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that the context to this quote is that Blackburn is contrasting what is sometimes called the 'presentist' view of time, in which we, and everything else, exist only in the now, the past is gone, the future does not exist yet, and time flows along, with the 'eternalist' or 'block' view of time in which all times exist and we, and everything else, have an existence that can be thought of as a line within a four-dimensional block of [spacetime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacetime) - i.e. the three spatial dimensions plus the time dimension, conceived as a single continuum.

The presentist view is more natural, because it accords with our conscious experience of time, and it allows us to draw a sharp distinction between the past, which we can no longer influence because it is gone, and the future, which we can influence because it is only a matter of possibility until it happens. The eternalist view is sometimes argued as being more consistent with the theories of relativity, although the whole issue is highly complex and much debated.

Blackburn mentions God, because many theists conceive God as existing outside of time entirely, and so for God at least the eternalist view makes more sense. So the question is, if God perceives time in an entirely symmetrical way, with no distinction between past and future, how is there any room for us to have the freedom to make things happen? Blackburn rather unhelpfully uses the term 'change', but this is misleading: we don't need to think of ourselves as changing things, only as bringing things about - I can't change the future, but I do have a part to play in bringing it about. Incidentally, not everyone agrees that we cannot bring about the past: Michael Dummett wrote a paper called Bringing about the Past in which he argued that this does make sense.

3, 4. You misread Blackburn's comment about omelettes, he is merely saying that an omelette must be made before it can be eaten - eating can only be followed by making if having eaten one you decide to make a second one and then eat that too.

5. In the paragraph marked [2] Blackburn asks whether our inability to bring about the past is just a *contingent* fact about our universe, or about the part of the universe we inhabit, or even about us. The alternative would be to suppose that our inability to bring about the past is somehow *necessary*, i.e. that bringing about the past is impossible in some way. We are all familiar with the paradoxes of backward time travel in science fiction stories, and some have claimed that this is logically impossible or inconceivable. Again, the issue is much debated, and it has been claimed that there could be loops of time, or wormholes, and that if we were somehow able to interact with the past we would simply need to amend our logic and our language to cope with it.

Comment: +1. Thanks as always. Please tell me if the edits offend you; I confirmed your thought of my misinterpretation, as I did misread Blackburn.

Comment: Maybe this is irrelevant, but what did you mean by `a four-dimensional block of spacetime`? 4D cannot be visualised; so I do not 'see' your meaning.

Answer (score 1):

We experience time asymmetrically. To us, the past seems fixed whereas the future seems unwritten, and therefore, malleable. We do not believe we can influence the past, but we do believe we can influence the future.

This may be an illusion. It may be that both the past and the future are fixed ("symmetrical"), that we can influence neither. This may be how a God outside of time perceives things. Imagine the universe like a movie reel, where the beginning of the reel is the "past" and the end of the reel is the "future." We are somewhere in between, experiencing each frame sequentially. But all frames exist simultaneously and eternally.

[1] Blackburn makes the subtle point that not even God can escape some asymmetry. There is an objective difference between the past and the future, between one end of the reel and the other, and the evidence is this: cooking omelettes always precedes eating omelettes. Never the other way around. (There are unlimited trivial examples that would serve to make the same point.)

Blackburn then makes what seems to me a leap, where he concludes: "So in fact, it is useless to try to influence the past." And conversely, by implication, it is *not* useless to try to influence the future. Neither of these follow.

[2] I honestly don't know what Blackburn is saying here. A few options:

1. If time is like a movie reel experienced sequentially in one direction, could we have experienced it going the reverse direction, like a tape on rewind? (But our labels of "past" and "future" would be reversed as well. So we would still regard "the past" as fixed and not subject to influence.)
2. Is it just locally that cooking omelettes precedes eating omelettes? Maybe in other universes, it happens the other way around? This touches on the concept of entropy. In our universe, as time appears to pass, entropy increases. But perhaps in other universes, as time appears to pass, entropy decreases. To outsiders, this might look like the present influencing the past, or time going in reverse. But only because we've been biased by our universe; we've come to equate "the past" with low-entropy states.
3. Assume that we can influence the future. Why, then, not the past? If there's no substantive difference between the two, if all of time is just "patterns," then *why* is our universe the way it is? Mere chance, or some innate feature of time? Is it impossible to influence the past in every universe, or only ours? (This is my best guess as to what Blackburn is saying, but I don't understand on what grounds he assumes we can influence the future.)